# I can not understand the change in x and y values in a rectangular structure

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a output which is `java.awt.Rectangle[x=40,y=55,width=20,height=30]`.
I do not understand the calculation method that happens in the middle.

```
{
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle (10,5,20,30);

    Rectangle rect2 = rect1;
    rect1.translate(20, 30);
    rect2.translate(10,20);
    System.out.println(rect1);
}
```

Comment: So, based on the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#translate-int-int-), `translate` basically offsets the x/y position of the rectangle by the specified amount. So, based on your example, the x position is `10 + 20 + 10` which is `40`. Before any one tells me there are two rectangles, remember, `rect2` and `rect1` both point to the same object

Comment: Remember - all object variables in Java are reference variables.  This isn't C++.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're only dealing with a single Rectangle instance. Even if you're calling translate on two different variables (rect1 and rect2) those variables still reference the same Rectangle because you set rect2 = rect1.

If you want two different Rectangles you have to manually instantiate another one.

Answer (score 0):

The [`translate(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#translate-int-int-) method simply moved the rectangle by the specified X and Y distances, without changing its size.

So the final X coordinate would be 10 (starting point) + 20 (first `translate` call) + 10 (second `translate` call) = 40.
Similarly, the final Y coordinate would be 5 (starting point) + 30 (first `translate` call) + 20 (second `translate` call) = 55.
The width and the height remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy :

```
10 + 20 + 10 = 40
5 + 30 + 20  = 55
20 + nothing = 20
30 + nothing = 30
```

Take a look in java doc how translate work [Rectangle::translate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#translate(int,%20int))